# Node JS Ubunto Production require error

Tags: javascript, ubuntu

I have deployed my Node js Application to digitalocean Ubuntu servers. Everything runs fine on localhost. For some reason when I start my node app using "node app.js" on ubuntu digital ocean, I am thrown "Cannot find module '../../Models". The "models" directory includes a few files that i have created including an index.js. My app is correctly configured and installed and I have been working on solving this issue for 2 days. Is ubuntu case sensitive for locating directories? I can't seem to figure out why my modules cannot be located. Thanks.

```
deploy@yw://home/deploy/ywapp$ node app

module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '../../Models'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/ywapp-1455754628602/routes/access_token/token.js:4:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/ywapp-1455754628602/routes/access_token/index.js:2:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/ywapp-1455754628602/routes/auth/user.js:13:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: Hi, can you put the entire error code?, Also try to make your question clearer

Comment: Also, please post the actual text of the stacktrace instead of an image.

Comment: Will that work? @mvlaicevich

Comment: yes @RobertChristopher, but please put the text not an image

Comment: what permissions does the folder Models has?, Also check that you are calling your module Models

Comment: isn't it just problem with case sensitivity? linux systems (like ubuntu) have mostly case sensitive file system, so if your module is called 'models' and you're requiring 'Models' it won't work. (I had that problem couple times while developing on mac and then deploying on debian..)

Comment: i think i agree with @lupatus. you said you created "models" folder but requiring a "Models". can you double check it ?